# setState with Firebase Promise in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database

How can i set state inside react component?

I`ve got error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null

here is the component code listing:

```
class MessageList extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   messages: []
 };

 var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
 firebaseRef.once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
      this.setState({
        messages: messages
      });
   });
 }

 render() { ... }

}
```

Comment: Excuse me, @benjamin-gruenbaum , but i meant why i couldnt get data from the firebase, and not about "this" key word

Comment: Your bug is because of the `this` keyword. I can either close this as incomplete or as a duplicate - for your sake and the sake of future visitors I think it's better to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 15):

***this*** is referring to the ***promise*** scope. Either use fat arrow functions (es6)

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
firebaseRef.once('value')
  .then((dataSnapshot) => {
      this.setState({
        messages: messages
      });
   });
```

Or create a copy of this before the promise

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   messages: []
 };
 var that = this; 
 var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
 firebaseRef.once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
      that.setState({
        messages: messages
      });
 });
```

One last option, you could bind this to the promise:

```
firebaseRef.once('value')
 .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
     this.setState({
         messages: messages
     });
}).bind(this)
```

Comment: This is working great. Thank you.

Comment: didn't think of creating a copy of 'this' prior to the firebase promise. genius, thanks

Answer (score 2):

At, first I want to suggest you that you fetch your initial `firebase` data
in `componentDidMount` component life cycle and to fix your `setState` issue you can follow the below code in where I've change the `self = this;` line only,

```
class MessageList extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   messages: []
 };

componentDidMount() {
 var self = this;
 var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
  firebaseRef.once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
    self.setState({
      messages: messages
    });
  });
 }
}

render() { ... }

}
```